# POSIX Regex notation to start and end with @ and Regex notation to have alphanumeric chars but Must contain an _

Tags: c, regex, expression, regular-language, qregularexpression

I currently using regex.h for a c program

wanted to ensure a string starts and ends with the @ which surrounds alphanumeric chars, (only 2 @'s none in the middle)

UPDATE: I think i fixed the first question by using the ^ and $ anchor tags. If that doesn't look like the right way to fix the problem please let me know.

my code right now:

```
(regexCheck(tag, "^[@]+[A-Za-z0-9]+[@]$") == 1)
```

additionally i wanted to make sure a string contained an _ with alphanumeric chars (eg. _test , te_st, test_ are all valid, but test is not valid)

my code right now:

```
(regexCheck(string, "[A-Za-z0-9_]")) == 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, but an explanation with regex grammar would also be appreciated.

Comment: I can never remember the differences between the different regex flavors, but did you try `^@[a-zA-z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`?

Comment: How many alphas need to be in the middle?  Is `@_@` a valid string?

Comment: yes @_@ is a valid string... but i think i fixed the first problem of the @ symbols with (regexCheck(tag, "^[@]+[A-Za-z0-9]+[@]$") == 1)

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. If there is some general concept which confuses you (like "how do I make sure a regex matches an entire string?"), that makes for a better question.

Comment: The first regex looks like it will unwantedly match `@@a@` and `@ab@` and will unwantely not match `@a_b@`.If I understood your goal correctly you want to fix all of that, right? I have a solution which would fix them, it would however also match `@_@`, is that ok? Your question could also be read like requiring anywhere between the @ at least one alphanumeric. I.e. it should match `@a_@` and `@_b@` but not `@_@`. Is that needed?

Comment: Try `^@[A-Za-z0-9]*_[A-Za-z0-9]*@$`

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^@[A-Za-z0-9]*_[A-Za-z0-9]*@$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nb2Cp6/1/). Note that you should specify the `REG_EXTENDED` flag when compiling the regex pattern so that `$` could be parsed correctly as the end of string anchor.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - 0 or more ASCII letters, digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - 0 or more ASCII letters, digits
- `@` - a `@` char
- `$` - end of string anchor.

Comment: This requires, and allows, a single underscore. Maybe the OP also needs to see how to allow repeated underscores? `^@[A-Za-z0-9](_[A-Za-z0-9]*)+$`